# apache nifi total execution time

Tags: time, execution, apache-nifi

I would like to know how to find out/capture the total execution time for any flow in Apache Nifi. Is there a way to do that and add it to the attributes list so that same can be shared over the PutEmail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you would have to add a custom timestamp property when the flowfile is received, do the bulk of your processing, then calculate an elapsed time attribute to include in the email.  You can do this with two UpdateAttribute processors.

1. UpdateAttribute, **received** = `${now():toNumber()}`
2. (do processing)
3. UpdateAttribute, **elapsed** = `${now():toNumber():minus(${received}):format("HH:mm:ss")}`

This will format the elapsed time like "00:04:16" (4 minutes, 16 seconds).  You can use this as `${elapsed}` in your PutEmail message content.

But this is a bit ugly and only gives an approximation of the processing time. The NiFi provenance system maintains "Lineage Duration", which describes the elapsed time since the file entered NiFi.  This is a far more authoritative number.  But I do not believe you can query lineage duration from expression language.  You would have to separately query and analyze the provenance data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that approach and it worked. I was able to capture the execution time with it.

Answer (score 10):

James provided an excellent explanation above. One additional note, though, is that rather than adding an attribute for the timestamp of when the data was received, you can simply reference the `lineageStartDate` attribute:

```
${now():toNumber():minus(${lineageStartDate}):format("HH:mm:‌​ss")}
```

This is the same value that is used to determine the Lineage Duration in the Provenance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean to say that instead of doing : (current time - start time) as suggested by @James above, i could directly use LineageStartDate attribute which would give me the duration of the process?

Comment: Should that be `${now():toNumber():minus(${lineageStartDate}):format("HH:mm:ss")}`?  Awesome, I didn't know that was accessible, +1!

Comment: Wow sorry - yes, that should have been `${now():toNumber():minus(${lineageStartDate}):format("HH:mm:ss")}`. Good catch on my typo :)

Comment: I had to do ${now():toNumber():minus(${lineageStartDate}):format("HH:mm:‌​ss", "GMT")} so that it would account for GMT offset